# copy constructor VS constructor with a class pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, constructor

**Q1:** Does the "self class typed pointer constructor" have a decent/official name?

**Q2:** Why is copy constructor much more famous than "self class typed pointer constructor"?

Or what are the cases that we must use copy constructor rather then "self class typed pointer constructor"?

```
class MyClass 
{
public:  
    int i;
    MyClass()
    {
        i = 20;
    }

    //Copy constructor
    MyClass(MyClass const & arg) 
    {
        i = arg.i;
    }

    //What kind of Constructor is this one? 
    MyClass(MyClass* pArg)
    {
        i = pArg->i;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass obj;
    MyClass* p = new MyClass();

    //call copy constructor
    MyClass newObj(obj);                //call copy constructor directly
    MyClass newObj2(*p);                //dereference pointer and then call copy constructor
    MyClass* pNew = new MyClass(*p);    //dereference pointer and then call copy constructor

    //Call THE constructor
    MyClass theObj(&obj);               //get the address, call THE constructor
    MyClass theObj2(p);                 //call pointer constructor directly
    MyClass* ptheNew = new MyClass(p);  //call pointer constructor directly
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has no special name, because there is nothing special about it.

The copy constructor is "more famous", because it is special.  It is special because it is a fundamental part of the way the language works.  If you don't declare a copy constructor, in most classes, one will be implicitly defined for you.  It is involved in many basic operations, such as these:

```
void foo(MyClass obj) // the copy ctor is (potentially) called to create this parameter
{
    ...
}

MyClass bar() // the copy ctor is (potentially) called when this function returns, and when it result is used
{
    ...
}

MyClass a;
MyClass b(a); // This calls the copy constructor
MyClass c = b; // So does this
```

Note that, in many cases, the copy is optimized away. See [Copy Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).  Also, in C++11, the [move constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_constructor#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) is called in many places where the copy constructor used to be called.  But the move constructor too can be optimized away in the same places that copy elision could happen.

I can't think of many reasons you would ever use "THE constructor", as you call it.

On a side note, a copy constructor should almost always have this signature:

```
MyClass(MyClass const &)
```

Not this one:

```
MyClass(MyClass &)
```

Comment: Thanks. did you miss a "&" in the declaration of copy constructor?

Comment: @milesma: In the declaration of what copy constructor?  I didn't declare one until just now, which was after you posted that comment so you couldn't have been talking about that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley He's probably referring to `foo`.

Comment: They are special, because they can be called by the language for explicit conversions. I've heard constructors that can be called with a single argument called "conversion constructors".

Comment: @MooingDuck For implicit conversion. But implicit conversion of `T *` to `T` by making a copy would be a total abomination. OP's example is simply missing an `explicit` keyword.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's a term for all single argument constructors though, not specific to constructors that take a pointer.

Comment: @milesma: If you're referring to `foo`, like Potatoswatter says, then no, nothing is missing there.  I'm taking the parameter by value, and so the copy constructor (or the move constructor) is called.  If there was a `&` there, then I would be taking the object in by reference, and no constructor would be called.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oooooh. May I understand in this way: when taking the parameter by value, it is reusing the copy constructor mechanism? Then that's a concrete reason why copy constructor is special.

Comment: @milesma: Yes, that's one reason.  Probably the main one.  Passing and returning by value utilizes the copy (or move) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To an object in C++, we usually use reference rather than pointer. We can use reference to get the address of the object, and than you can use '.' to access its method or data, it is more simple and direct than '->'.
I think there is no need to use 'THE constructor'.

Comment: Thanks, actually that's the reason I thought as well. But I still think there is "something" more special for a copy constructor. That is why I'm posting this.

Comment: @milesma Aside from the sort of answer provided by Ben, references are special because they can't be null. The pointer constructor would presumably select either the copy constructor or the default constructor, so it would be less primitive.

Comment: @Potatoswatter +1 for reference can't be null, so it is more safe inside the function. Then may I say the "self typed pointer constructor" can do the same job as copy constructor if "check pointer" is provided?

Comment: @milesma It's up to you what it does. Whereas the Standard imposes some requirements on copy constructors, for objects passed to standard facilities, "pointer constructors" are your own domain. I just assumed that your original intent was to check for null, and in that case use the default value.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks. Actually I know how to write copy constructor; I'm OK to confirm to standard. This post is just trying to "dig" a bit deeper in case I can find some treasure (know why copy constructor is special).